# Facebook apps is working in case of my (administrator) account though sandbox is disabled

Tags: facebook-apps

I have developed a facebook application that post images to user account. I have registered that apps. When I run my code it should post image to the user wall who is logged in. It is working only my account is logged in. If some other people logs in and run my PHP script then no error is found but actually image is not posting to that user's wall. I have disabled the sandbox too. What could be the other reasons?

Please let me know if you need my source code.

```
<?php

include("facebook.php");
$filename ="50ed5eb3b33d0.png";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'cookie' => TRUE,
  ));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if(!$user)
{
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, user_photos, read_stream, read_friendlists'
        ));

     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";

}
else
{

        try {

                $uid = $facebook->getUser();

                $facebook->setFileUploadSupport( true );
                $parameters = array(
                    'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
                    'message' => 'PHOTO_CAPTION',
                    'image' => '@' . realpath( './images/'.$filename ) 
                );

                $post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/photos', 'POST', $parameters);

                if(isset($post_id))
                {
                    echo "Thank you for posting" .$uid;
                    unlink('./images/'.$filename);  
                }

        }//end try getUser 
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);

        }//end of catch getUser 
}//end of else user

?>
```

Comment: Share the code that you are using to post/upload

Comment: And the error message you're receiving

Comment: I have added the source code. @lgy-- Actually I am not getting any error . But whey some other people logs in from facebook and try to use this script image is not posting to his wall. But when I log in image is posting to my wall. I am the administrator of the registered apps.

Comment: `req_perms` is an outdated parameter for creating the login URL. Use `scope` instead, that's the current way to ask for permissions.

Comment: @CBroe -- thanks a lot. Now it works for me. By the way the FB documents seems a bit poor in terms of description to me. Can you please help me one concept? Suppose user has removed my app and try to run this script then what should happen? In my case it is giving error.. "Error validating access token: User 100001660133284 has not authorized application 422333384503110" and the code number is 190 . But is it possible that if user removed this app from his account then if he runs this script then he will be asked to access this apps again?